# watch changes of nested data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to watch changes of families variable which contains nested objects

```
 <component-test
    v-for="family of familiesToDisplay"
    // rest
   />

data: () => ({
    families: [],
  }),

      computed: {
        familiesToDisplay() {
          return this.families.fillter(family => family.members > 4);
        },
    
      },
```

In some response I have seen some recomanding the use of watch but in my case I didn't knew how to implement it since I have never used before.
so the request is to get changes of nested objects in families (as objects I have person and work so if a name of a person has been changed or its work has been changed changes must be retreived here)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine, however, it is necessary to correctly mutate objects inside an array. You need to use `this.$set` or replace the object with a new one to trigger vue re-rendering a list and recalculation of a list.
For example, you can change them like this, (full working example you can find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-with-deep-reactivity-cc9e2z)):

```js
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    Display,
  },

  data: () => ({
    families: [
      { name: "foo-1", members: 1 },
      { name: "foo-5", members: 5 },
      { name: "bar-6", members: 6 },
      { name: "bar-3", members: 3 },
    ],
  }),

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.families.forEach((family) => {
        this.$set(family, "members", this.getRandomNumber());
      });
    },

    getRandomNumber() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    },
  },
};
```